# PHPMyAdmin | Event Scheduler cannot enabled and get #1577 error

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

I've stuck on this problem for a while. 
I need to schedule a job for my query daily so I have to `set global event_scheduler = ON`

and I got this message ..

## 1577 - Cannot proceed because system tables used by Event Scheduler were found damaged at server start

some guys told me i have to restart db and do it again but it's not work.
I was going to `my.cnf` and type `event_scheduler = ON` in `[mysqld]` section and restart again
and it's still **DISABLED**.

someone told me it's a bug of version 5.5 but i'm using 5.6 .....

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.22-72.0         |
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| slave_type_conversions  |                     |
| version                 | 10.0.17-MariaDB     |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | i386                |
| version_compile_os      | osx10.6             |
| version_malloc_library  | system              |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

so I have no any idea what should i do with this thing :(
I also can't access the EVENT table in information_schema db with the same error.
if anyone can solve my problem. i'll owe you guys my entire life.

 ** i sincerely apologise if it's a stupid question **
Ps. I use XAMPP.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a good idea to research error codes and messages:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/385015/mysql-damaged-system-tables
- https://serverfault.com/questions/562282/mysqldump-error-1557-corrupt-event-table
- https://serverfault.com/questions/100685/cannot-proceed-because-system-tables-used-by-event-scheduler-were-found-damaged
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70975